# Accesssing a private struct defined in class by a friend or a member function

Tags: c++, oop, private-members, friend-function, public-method

I want to make a public: or friend function to a class return the address of a pointer whose type is defined as a private member of the class.

Example:-

```
class LinkedList{

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* head = NULL;
Node* tail = NULL;
Node* createNode(int value)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

public:
    //other functions in the class
    LinkedList(int*, int, bool);
    void insertNodeBeg(int value);
    void insertNodeEnd(int value);
    void printList();
    void deleteList();

    //someway to do this:-
    Node* reverseList();
};
/* implementation of other function not shown*/

void reverseList(LinkedList head)
{
    Node* temp = head;
    /*---
     code that reverse the list,
     sets head to point to the new first node, and then I want to return head.
---*/
        return head;
    }
```

Now I want the struct to be private as I don't want the user to access it any other way.
I also need to return the address as I want the user to have the ability to create a new list by reversing the existing one.

something like this:-

> new_list = old_list.reverseList();

but I don't want to create a new list, so to say.

I would like someone to help me with this or to just direct me to another source or answer.

Comment: Surely what `reverseList` should do is return a LinkedList? [And probably be a member function, but that's a different matter]

Comment: For now I just want it to return the address of the head pointer.

Comment: No, you do not, unless you want to make `Node` public, because there is nothing useful you can do with it outside of a `LinkedList`. This is indicated also by the fact that your example is `new_list = old_list.reverseList();` [which is a member function call, you perhaps meant `new_list = reverseList(old_list)`?

Comment: Note also that if you are modifying the nodes inside the existing list, your `old_list` will change, which is probably not a desireable feature.

Comment: So there is no other way to return head pointer without making Node public?

Comment: @DivyangVashi You can make the name public without making the definition public, but there isn't much you can do without the definition. Why do you want to do it? If you want to reverse the list in-place without creating a new one, do it and don't return anything. If you want the reversal to create a new list, don't reverse in-place but return the new list.

Comment: How can I make the definition public?